# How is folder redirection configured on Linux Clients?

Tags: samba, active-directory, domain

I'm wanting to configure home directories on my Linux clients to be redirected to my samba AD-DC homes share. I tried using fstab to mount the user's home directory in /home, that creates issues for PAM causing the user to not be able to log in. It also doesn't create the `/home/<username>` directory

According to this [thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1960345) if the [homes] share is configured it should happen "automagically". But after joining the client to the domain and logging in as domain user the /home directory is created(with a (empty)home directory folder structure) but not redirected to user's folder on the [homes] share.